# Sorting by date with AppEngine search API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have documents with a contents TextField and a date DateField. I am trying to fetch the most recent documents.

- A regular search with 'date > epoch' seems to already sort the
  results by date. Is that an expected behavior?
- When I try to explicitly sort with SortExpression the results are not even sorted in any particular order (except on the dev server where it seems to work as well).

I am using the following code:

```
index.search(search.Query(query_string='date > epoch', 
                          options=search.QueryOptions(
                            sort_options=search.SortOptions(
                              expressions=[search.SortExpression(
                                 expression='date', 
                                 direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING, 
                                 default_value='1970-01-01')])))
```

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, all documents are sorted by their rank unless you specify a different sorting option. And a document rank is set to the time when it was added to the index, again, unless you specify a different rank.

If this is your desired behavior, there is no need to add a date field and sort by it.

Answer (score 1):

When you filter by a field your are forcing to use index and as side result the output will be sorted by that field.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/options

> When you call the search() method using a query string alone, the
>   results are returned according to the default query options:
>
> - Documents are returned sorted in order of descending rank
> - Documents are returned in groups of 20 at a time
> - Retrieved documents contain all of their original fields

Don't know why it does not work with explicit sorting options.